# How do you improve the performance of the Health Cloud?

Tags: performance, health-cloud

Currently the load time of the Health Cloud is subpar, I have ran it with a computer with the latest release of Chrome, 16 GB of Ram and a 200 Mb  connection to the internet, despite that the health cloud takes too much time loading. How can the performance of the Health Cloud be improved?